# Material-UI Dialog background shadow flickers under certain conditions

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get a material-ui dialog to have tabs, however the background shadow flickers in dark themes for some reason. This only happens when the tab switches.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-tu-5p9wl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the same happens for the light theme, just that the shadow is less perceptible and blend better, if it truly is bothering you, you can disable the ripples from the tabs `disableRipple`

```js
  <Tabs value={tab} variant="fullWidth" onChange={(_, n) => setTab(n)}>
    <Tab label="Join Guild" disableRipple />
    <Tab label="Create Guild" disableRipple />
  </Tabs>
```

This way the shadow problem is fixed, but you lose the ripple effect, you can open an issue at their github repo and see if they can fix it at the core